# how to limit one label while doing multi-label classification

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, multilabel

I have a data set with 7 labels. I would like to apply multi-label classification on that. by that, each instance may have more than one label associated.

now let's explain what I want.

Rules in my dataset for the labels:

1. each instance may have one or more than one labels BUT when the instance label is `others` it will not have any other label.
   For example:

   NEVER, NEVER take this drug. => others

here the label is `others` so my model should not predict any other label with that.

But I printed the result of the test set and I saw most of the time this label has been repeated in other labels.
For example, the result of the test set for this instance is that:

```
NEVER, NEVER take this drug. => others, ADR
```

but as the true label is `others` it should never be predicted by another label

Is there any approach I can do that it prevents my classifier to predict this label with other labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of multi-label classification is that predicted properties are not mutually exclusive, which is not true in your case. You could take the label `others` away from the multi-label classifier and build a binary classifier for it. Run the multi-label classifier only if the binary classifier predicts the label of an instance is not `others`.

---

Edit: Add the following block diagram to elaborate on the multi-stage prediction approach.

[image: multi-stage prediction]

Comment: +1 Multi-stage prediction is often useful -- regardless of the toolkit you use.

Comment: @tuomastic thank you so much for the answer. so you mean firstly I should apply the same classifier but in the binary version.  and then apply multi-label classifier? in this case how can get a total average f1 measurement? or you mean this is needed to be done in two different steps so no way to get an estimation of the whole dataset?

Comment: can you please elaborate more about your approach?

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi I have edited the answer by adding a block diagram of the multi-stage prediction. The binary classifier predicts if _others_ is 0 or 1. If _others_ is 1, the other labels are 0. If _others_ is 0, the other labels are predicted by the multi-label classifier.

Comment: @tuomastik thank you so much for the diagram, what if the binary classifier accuracy is not high so it misses a bunch of others? like if the accuracy of binary s 75 percent do you think it still makes sense to apply this?

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi Well, you didn't seem happy with your original approach either so I guess it's a trade-off. In the multi-stage approach, you at least get predictions in a correct format.